# SwiftUI tab view display sheet

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm new to SwiftUI and I tried to build a tab bar that contained a tab that will return a modal(sheet) but not view. After I tried I found sometimes it will work but sometime are not. I want to make the previous tabbed item as the selected tab after the user dismissed the modal. But I can't find what the error. Anyone explains to me what the problem of my code?

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresenting = false
    @State private var selectedItem = 1
    @State private var oldSelectedItem = 1


    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem){
            Text("1")
                .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                }.tag(1)
            .onAppear {
                self.oldSelectedItem = self.selectedItem
            }

            Text("")    // I want this to display the sheet.
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "plus.circle") }
                .tag(2)
            .onAppear {
                self.isPresenting = true
                self.selectedItem = self.oldSelectedItem

            }

            Text("3")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                }.tag(3)
            .onAppear {
                self.oldSelectedItem = self.selectedItem
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
            testSheet
        }
        .accentColor(Color.orange)

    
    }
    var testSheet : some View {
        VStack{
            Text("testing")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `TabView` selection to activate sheet programmatically, but do not actually allow this selection to be changed (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14).

Update: retested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresenting = false
    @State private var selectedItem = 1
    @State private var oldSelectedItem = 1


    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem){
            Text("1")
                .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                }.tag(1)

            Text("")    // I want this to display the sheet.
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "plus.circle") }
                .tag(2)

            Text("3")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                }.tag(3)
        }
     //   .onReceive(Just(selectedItem))  // SwiftUI 1.0 - import Combine for this
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) {    // SwiftUI 2.0 track changes
                if 2 == selectedItem {
                self.isPresenting = true
                } else {
                    self.oldSelectedItem = $0
                }
            }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting, onDismiss: {
                self.selectedItem = self.oldSelectedItem
            }) {
            testSheet
        }
        .accentColor(Color.orange)


    }
    var testSheet : some View {
        VStack{
            Text("testing")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its work! thank you so much! I got another question, can I make the second view empty instead of ```Text("")```?

Comment: Wow The only answer that got it right. Other answers work but not 100%. This Works 100% Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A small change to `Martijn Pieters`'s answer:-

The original code changes the current tab to a blank tab behind the sheet. This update addresses this issue by keeping the last selected tab alive.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresenting = false
    @State private var selectedItem = 1
    @State private var oldSelectedItem = 1


    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedItem){
            Text("1")
                .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                }.tag(1)

            Text("")    // I want this to display the sheet.
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "plus.circle") }
                .tag(2)

            Text("3")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                }.tag(3)
        }
     //   .onReceive(Just(selectedItem))  // SwiftUI 1.0 - import Combine for this
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) {    // SwiftUI 2.0 track changes
                if 2 == selectedItem {
                self.isPresenting = true
                self.selectedItem = self.oldSelectedItem
                } else if (isPresented == false) {
                    self.oldSelectedItem = $0
                }
            }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
            testSheet
        }
        .accentColor(Color.orange)


    }
    var testSheet : some View {
        VStack{
            Text("testing")
        }
    }
}
```

After user clicks on the sheet option, the `onChange` listener restores `self.oldselecteditem` as the active tab. The dismiss event listener on the sheet has been removed since the last active tab is already active and the listener would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Add the code below to your `TabView`

```swift
.onChange(of: selectedItem) { newValue in
    if newValue == 2 {
        isPresenting = true
        selectedItem = oldSelectedItem
    } else {
        oldSelectedItem = newValue
    }
}
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresenting) {
    // Sheet view
}
```